# In Haskell, is it possible to qualify part of an imported module?

Tags: haskell

I'd like to be able to do something like: `import qualified Data.Massiv.Array (qualified map)`.

This gives `` error: parse error on input `map' ``.

Or better yet, `import qualified Data.Massiv.Array (qualified map) as AM`, so I also can access `foo` as either `foo` or `AM.foo`, unless `foo` == `map`, then I have to use `AM.map`. This is to avoid conflict with `Prelude.map`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Write two `import`s and you can use `map` as `AM.map` and use other functions without `AM.`.

```
import qualified Data.Massiv.Array as AM
import Data.Massiv.Array hiding (map)
```

Comment: And if, for some reason, you don't want the names like `Data.Massiv.Array.foo` to be defined -- only `foo` and `AM.foo` -- you can even combine `as` and `hiding` in the second import; `import Data.Massiv.Array as AM hiding (map)`.